# string split and compare

Tags: java, split, trim

My intention is to remove the whitespaces and semicolons and if one of the resulting string matches "quit"...I'll print "Yikes!"

I am not sure as to why this is not working.

```
    String someString = "abc   ;        def   ;quit";
    String[] someArray = someString.split(";");

    for(int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        someArray[i] = someArray[i].trim();
        if(someArray[i] == "quit") {
            System.out.println("Yikes!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note : use `split("\\s*;)` instead of `split(";")`

Comment: String someString = "abc   ;        def   ;quit";
        someString = someString.replace(" ", "");
        System.out.println("H:"+someString);
        
        String[] someArray = someString.split(";");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
            someArray[i] = someArray[i].trim();
            
            if (someArray[i].equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Yikes!");
            }
        }

Comment: Thanks. Does this `split("\\s*;")` mean..one or more spaces and semicolon?